# How can I change change links to point to custom domain on Azure Webites

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I bought a custom domain from godaddy and made a wordpress blog with Azure Websites. Everything worked fine, my custom domain name is working but I have a small problem.

Let's say that my custom domain name is "azuresite". Well, I have the domain "azuresite.com", but when I go to the website and I click on a link (let's say the about page), it goes to azuresite.azurewebsites.com/about instead of going to azuresite.com/about

Do you have any idea what should I do to make the links point to my custom domain instead of the azurewebsites domain?

Here are two screenshots that may help you to better understand the problem:
GoDaddy Zone file: http://prntscr.com/2ida3c
Screenshot of my website:  http://prntscr.com/2idaqg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I just had to go to wordpress settings and change my site address from mydomain.azurewebsites.net to mydomain.com. Here's a screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/2kjwzp