# Mapped custom domain still showing *.azurewebsites.net

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Hi I have set up the A Record and C Name on my GoDaddy's Domain to Azure App Services (website). In the Azure portal it also shows it has successfully validated the Domain name. However, when I type < mysite >.com on the browser's address bar, it loads the site correctly but it still shows .azurewebsites.net after it loads.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658634/custom-domain-name-on-azure-site-working-but-always-redirects-to-azurewebsites) and setup masked domain forwarding in GoDaddy. However it still doesn't work?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: did you assign hostnames to azure webapp?

Comment: Is it a wordpress site ? If yes please have a try to change wordpress setttings from azurewebsite.net name to custom domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099949/how-can-i-change-change-links-to-point-to-custom-domain-on-azure-webites?rq=1 .More details about how to map a custom domain,please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name#step-1-a-record-only-get-apps-ip-address).

Comment: yes it is a wordpress site... i have followed your link in your comment and has resolved the problem THANKS A BUNCH!!

Comment: I've supplied it as an answer, if it is marked  that it will be more helpful for the communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a WordPress website, please have a try to change WordPress settings from azurewebsite.net name to custom domain, more info please refer to the the similar SO [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099949/how-can-i-change-change-links-to-point-to-custom-domain-on-azure-webites?rq=1) More details about how to map a custom domain, please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name#step-1-a-record-only-get-apps-ip-address).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something in your site redirects to the azurewebsites.net hostname.
If you have no idea what it is, then you can try to check out the Chrome F12 tools to look at the network traffic and figure out where the redirect (http status code 30x) comes from.